# xhtml->docx->xhtml retain div ids?

Tags: java, xhtml, docx, docx4j

I'm attempting to export some CKEditor created xhtml fields from a database, convert them to a docx, edit the document in Word, then convert it back to xhtml and import those fields back into the database.  I'm currently using docx4j-XHTMLImport, but I'm open to suggestions.

The xhtml structure is like:

```
<html><body>
<div id="database-field-1" class="field-section">
    <label>database-field-1</label>
    <div class="field-content">xyz</div>
</div>
<div id="database-field-2" class="field-section">
    <label>database-field-2</label>
    <div class="field-content">xyz</div>
</div>
```

etc...

So when converting between formats I would like to retain the id's from the divs so when I import again, I can parse the xhtml and extract the fields per id to update the database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the divs to content controls.

See [XHTML-docx roundtrip: content tracking](http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2014/09/xhtml-docx-roundtrip-content-tracking/) (just written).

Comment: Thanks Jason!  Was able to convert html->docx->html!